# Problems with Django URL routing

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm building a website, to be used in dental practices, however I'm having trouble with the URL routing. I'm wanting af URL pattern like: Denthelp/kartotek/#nameofclinic#/opretpatient.
My suggestion looks like this:

urls.py:

```
path('kartotek/<str:kl_id>/', views.kartotek, name="kartotek"),
path('kartotek/<str:kl_id>/opretpatient/', views.opretpatient, name="opret_patient"),
```

Views. py:

```
def kartotek(request, kl_id):
kliniknavn = Klinik.objects.get(navn=kl_id)
E_patient = kliniknavn.patient_set.all()
context = { 'kliniknavn':kliniknavn, 'E_patient':E_patient}
return render(request,'DentHelp/kartotek.html', context )

def opretpatient(request, kl_id):
kliniknavn = Klinik.objects.get(navn=kl_id)

form = PatientForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PatientForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('kartotek/<str:kl_id>/')

context = {'form':form, 'kliniknavn':kliniknavn}
return render(request,'DentHelp/kartotek/<str:kl_id>/opretpatient.html', context)
```

When running code I get an OSError for the last line of code shown here.

Have you guys have any advise for this to work?

Comment: Yeah, you are trying to get file on path DentHelp/kartotek/<str:kl_id>/opretpatient.html which mose likely does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) with [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect). `render` renders a template **dynamically** with attributes from `context`, where `redirect` redirects the user to a different view. To call `render`, you need to provide template name and context. For redirect, you need to provide url name and parameters (if required). Here is how you should do in your code:

```
def opretpatient(request, kl_id):
    kliniknavn = Klinik.objects.get(navn=kl_id)
    
    form = PatientForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PatientForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('kartotek', kl_id)  # url name and parameter

context = {'form':form, 'kliniknavn':kliniknavn}
return render(request, 'DentHelp/kartotek/opretpatient.html', context)  # template name and context
```

Comment: Ah! Makes sense! I'm having trouble with the query in the template file,, where I want to have a link-button to the patient page. I have tried the {{ url opretpatient klinik.navn}} but that doesnt seem to work? any advises?